# Extract the text in element by using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am able to fetch the text in `td` element by BeautifulSoup. However, this includes characters that I don't want. I just want the numbers, how can I remove the characters?

The code looks like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

record = []
hksi = ['CKH']

url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/futures/futures_stockoptions.php?atscode={}&month=202101"

for s in hksi:
    response = requests.get(url.format(s))
    info = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(info, "lxml")
    
    bid = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 10px; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text
    ratio = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text
    ask = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 10px 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text

    record.append({
        'symbol' : s,
        'bid' : bid,
        'ask' : ask,
        'ratio': ratio
    })
print(bid)
```

Output:

```
認購總數 1441
```

I want to remove the "認購總數", and the output should look like this:

```
1441
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to account for the three variables `bid`, `ratio` and `ask`, a neat approach is to simply use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with this substitution:

```
val = re.sub(r'[^!-~]', '', val)
```

for each of `bid`, `ratio` and `ask`.

This removes anything but printable ASCII characters, and also removes spaces. If you want to keep the spaces, then instead do:

```
val = re.sub(r'[^ -~]', '', val)
```

You could also make the pattern more specific, keeping only digits, `.`, `:`, `%` or whatever characters make sense depending on other fields you may need to extract, e.g.

```
val = re.sub(r'[^0-9:\.%]', '', val)
```

Here is a full working version:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

record = []
hksi = ['CKH']

url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/futures/futures_stockoptions.php?atscode={}&month=202101"

for s in hksi:
    response = requests.get(url.format(s))
    info = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(info, "lxml")
    
    bid = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 10px; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text
    ratio = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text
    ask = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 10px 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text

    record.append({
        'symbol' : s,
        'bid' : bid,
        'ask' : ask,
        'ratio': ratio
    })
for val in [bid, ratio, ask]:
    val = re.sub(r'[^!-~]', '', val)
    print(val)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use this method, the ratio variable will output "7723", may I know how can I fix it?

Comment: @janicewww see my updated response -- it removes everything but printable ASCII characters from the `bid`, `ratio` and `ask`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to only get the numbers from your string. Using `' (\d+)'` will only match digits that follow a space.

```
import re

bid = '認購總數 1441'
number = re.findall(' (\d+)', bid)
print(int(number[0]))
```

Output:

```
1441
```

Alternatively, if `bid` will always have the same structure, i.e. characters followed by space followed by digits, you can split on space and get the last element:

```
bid = '認購總數 1441'
number = bit.split(' ')[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use this method, the ratio variable will output "77", may I know how can I fix it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you also want to capture things like "77:23". In this case you can use this regex: `' (\d+:?\d+)'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression, to search only for something that matches the patter you expect:

If you look for something like 2.3 or 2:3

use (case 2.3):

```
\d+(?:\.)+\d+
```

or use (case 2:3):

```
\d+(?:\:)+\d+
```

This code will work with input like 23:2:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


record = []
hksi = ['CKH']

url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/futures/futures_stockoptions.php?atscode={}&month=202101"

for s in hksi:
    response = requests.get(url.format(s))
    info = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(info, "lxml")
    
    bid = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 10px; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text
    ratio = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text
    ask = soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 10px 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text

    record.append({
        'symbol' : s,
        'bid' : bid,
        'ask' : ask,
        'ratio': ratio
    })
numbers = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\:)+\d+')
output = numbers.findall(bid)
print(output[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use this method, the ratio variable will output "77,23" but I want the ouput is 77:23. May I know how can I fix it?

Comment: In this case the regex should be updated, please check again the code

Answer (score 0):

To only get the digits, filter for the elements by checking if it [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

For example, create a function to filter the digits:

```
def filter_digits(tag):
    return ''.join(element for element in tag if element.isdigit())
```

```
...
for s in hksi:
    response = requests.get(url.format(s))
    info = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(info, "lxml")

    bid = filter_digits(soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 10px; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text)
    ratio = filter_digits(soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 0 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text)
    ask = filter_digits(soup.find('td', {'style': 'padding:10px 10px 5px 0; border-top:1px dotted #e2e2e2; font-weight:bold;'}).text)

    print(bid)
    print(ratio)
    print(ask)
```

Output (currently):

```
556
5644
434
```